# Django Dynamic Form Selection

Tags: django, forms, dynamic, selection

I want to achieve Dynamic form selection using Django

```
Vehicle_Type_Choices = (
    (‘car’,’Car’),
    (‘bike’,’Bike’),
    (‘auto’,’Auto’),
)
vehicle_type = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=Vehicle_Type_Choices)
```

Now I have 3 different forms (I.e `CarForm`, `BikeForm`, `AutoForm`) for `Vehicle` specifications based on the type of vehicle selected.

Now, I want if the user selects the Choice `Car` above, I want to display the `CarForm` (or) if the user selects `Bike`,  then `BikeForm` has to be displayed for further filling of Data.

Please Help me to achieve the above scenario .
Thanks and regards

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ? "Please Help me to achieve the above scenario" is not really a question and there are quite a few different ways (all well known - the problem is nothing new) to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most simple ways would be to just go to another page after a selection has been made (i.e. wizard type), anything else would need lots of javascript.

There is one package that can do form splitting, but never use it and not sure if/how can help in your situation, but I guess its worth taking a look: [django-formtools](https://github.com/django/django-formtools)